# Alternative way to call class method by param or string

Tags: ruby

I would like to pass a class method as a parameter to have another object call it ie

```
do_this(Class.method_name)
```

and then:

```
def do_this(class_method)
  y = class_method(local_var_x)
end
```

The only way I can see to do it is pass it as a string and use eval, or pass the class and method as a string, then constantize and send.  Downside to eval seems to be speed and debugging?

Is there an easier way to do this?

Edit:

Good answers but realized I asked the question slightly wrong, would like to use a parameter not passed with the method.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest an approach similar to the second solution you proposed.

```
do_this(Class.method(:name), x)
```

and then:

```
def do_this(method, x)
   y = method.call(x)
end
```

See also the documentation of [`Object#method`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-method).

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a proc object:

```
def do_this(myproc)
    y = myproc.call
end
```

and then

```
do_this( Proc.new { klass.method(x) } )
```

though you should also consider using block, which is much more in the ruby style.  That would look like:

```
def do_this
   y = yield
end
```

and call via:

```
do_this { klass.method(x) }
```